# Pyomo constraints to enforce integer variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, ipopt

In the problem described below, I try to find the optimal mix of batch size and number of production runs to meet at minimum certain outcome value. While I am quite sure that for the given data constellation the problem is indeed infeasible, I want to avoid that solver returns infeasible due to "human error" ;)

Running the code below with `ipopt`, it gives the following feasible result:

> Optimal number of batches (x): 0.9999999903937844
>
> Optimal batch size (a): 6.363636302503406
>
> Optimal total production: 6.3636362413729435

However, the values of variables a and x should be **integer**.

1. How can I refine my constraints as I learned that Pyomo is not accepting constraints which return boolean?
2. How can I formulate the constraint that 0.2*a and 0.8*a are integer? If boolean expressions were allowed, it would be something like `float(0.2*a).is_integer()`.

The code:

```py
model.x = Var(name="Number of batches", domain=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=10)                    
model.a = Var(name="Batch Size", domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(5,20))

# Objective function
def total_production(model):
    return model.x * model.a
model.total_production = Objective(rule=total_production, sense=minimize)

# Constraints
# Minimum production of the two output products
def first_material_constraint_rule(model):
    return sum(0.2 * model.a * i for i in range(1, value(model.x)+1)) >= 70
model.first_material_constraint = Constraint(rule=first_material_constraint_rule)

def second_material_constraint_rule(model):
    return sum(0.8 * model.a * i for i in range(1, value(model.x)+1)) >= 90
model.second_material_constraint = Constraint(rule=second_material_constraint_rule)

# At least one production run
def min_production_rule(model):
    return model.x >= 1
model.min_production = Constraint(rule=min_production_rule)
```

Comment: (1) This looks like a non-convex MINLP. (2) `value(model.x)` in a constraint?

Comment: @Erwin: Can you elaborate a bit on your second point and give me more context?

Comment: Looks bad to me to use an initial value to size something. Initial values are not sizes but are, well, initial values. It may not even mean what you think.

Comment: ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x ... this is thrown if initialize=10 is left out.

Comment: That is correct. You use the initial value to size something. Likely not what you mean.

Comment: `ipopt `is a non-linear **continuous** solver. It naturally does not support integer/boolean constraints. 
Dispute you can always formulate a boolean via continuous (1-x)*x = 0, it does not work in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have pyomo so I demonstrate with `differential_evolution`. Maintaining that `0.2a`, `0.8a` and `a` are all integers is easy by defining the decision variable as 0.2*a, and deriving `a` within the objective and constraint functions. Also, don't run a `sum` within the constraint; that evaluates to x(x + 1)/2:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution, Bounds, NonlinearConstraint


def total_production(xa02: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x, a02 = xa02
    a = a02/0.2
    return x*a


def first_material_constraint_rule(xa02: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x, a02 = xa02
    return a02 * x*(x + 1)/2


def second_material_constraint_rule(xa02: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x, a02 = xa02
    a = a02/0.2
    return 0.8*a * x*(x + 1)/2


# Variables: x, non-negative integer, number of batches;
#         0.2a, non-negative integer, where a is the batch size.
result = differential_evolution(
    func=total_production,
    x0=(10, 1),
    integrality=(True, True),
    bounds=Bounds(
        # 1 <= x <= large, 5 <= a <= 20
        lb=(1, 5*0.2),
        ub=(1000, 20*0.2),
    ),
    constraints=(
        NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=first_material_constraint_rule, lb=70, ub=np.inf),
        NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=second_material_constraint_rule, lb=90, ub=np.inf),
    ),
)
assert result.success
x, a02 = result.x
a = a02/0.2
print('x =', x)
print('a =', a)
print('0.2a =', a02)
print('0.8a =', a*0.8)
print('total production =', result.fun)
print('first material =', sum(0.2*a*i for i in range(1, int(round(x))+1)))
print('second material =', sum(0.8*a*i for i in range(1, int(round(x))+1)))
```

```
x = 12.0
a = 5.0
0.2a = 1.0
0.8a = 4.0
total production = 60.0
first material = 78.0
second material = 312.0
```